# How to import 55k images (uploaded via FTP) into Wordpress Media libary?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media, media-library, ftp

I have got 55k images in my Wordpress Uploads folder which are not showing up in the Media Libary, how can I make them registered there ?

I tried the plugin 'Add from Server' but there are to many images, and the Plugin fails to do anything.

Any other suggestions, how I could try to add the images into the media libary ?

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like asking for a plugin recommendation which is off-topic.